# Spring SAML SSO - IDP Metadata does not contain SingleSignOnService

Tags: java, spring, saml, spring-saml

I have a Spring SAML app that works with my test IDP server.

It does not work with a 3rd party IDP server I was given metadata for.

The metadata given to me does not include any `SingleSignOnService` definitions, and really does not include any endpoint URLs at all.

Is there another way to create an endpoint URL to associate with this metadata file?  I looked here and did not see anything that looked promising:

https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x/reference/html/configuration-sso.html

Comment: May be if you can upload the metadata here, you can get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that metadata without SingleSignOnService endpoint cannot be used for SAML 2.0 WebSSO profile. You should contact the IDP team for more guidance.